# Is there a way to yank directly to a vimscript variable?

Tags: vimscript

I have some boilerplate code in one of my vimscript functions:

```
" Save register 'a' so we don't clobber it
let savereg = @a

" Yank the current WORD into register 'a' and save it to 'input'
normal "ayiW
let input = @a

" Restore register 'a' so we don't clobber it
let @a = l:savereg

"
" ... Do work on 'l:input'
"
```

Is there a better way to do what I want? That is, to operate on a `WORD` (or any text object, really) without clobbering a register?

Comment: If I knew how to operate on the range `'<,'>` then my problem would be solved, I believe. But I'm not sure how to get text from between 2 marks. I'm reading the documentation but I'm quite lost... I am looking for a starting point or a hint.

Comment: yes, but it is clumsy. Use the `getline()` functions and in combination with the cursor position, select the needed part of the line

Comment: @AriSweedler Since you sound eager to learn but maybe not grokking the help docs this is a widely praised route to enlightenment: [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com) (Not for newbies but doesn't look like that's you. At the very least bookmark it for the future.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if your script runs from a mapping than you probably should support `v:register` - let the user decide what to use.

Next, if your operation is a sort of "visual replacement" (get selection, modify and put it back) it makes sense to model it after `:h v_p` (maybe even end it with `gvp` or such).

In this case either `@-` (for "less-than-a-line" selection) or `@9` (for a multiline selection) will be overwritten anyway, so you can make use of one of them in your script.

Otherwise, I prefer simply to clobber `@0` as it seems like a natural choice. Anyway, it gets overwritten quite often, and it could also be a good idea to spare "original input" for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the tips about best practice! I consider that invaluable. What I am really trying to accomplish a macro that reads a WORD under the cursor and does work on it. Specifically, I want to be able to append "(due in 5 days)" with a single keystroke when my cursor is over a date that's 5 days in the future. That wouldn't be a very good question to ask here, tho. What I wrote can be found here, if you're curious: https://github.com/AriSweedler/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/plugin/due.vim

Comment: @AriSweedler In your specific case it's probably sufficient to do simply `expand('<cWORD>')`

Comment: I am so stoked to be learning this stuff. You are right, and thank you for the improvement.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a better way to do what I want? That is, to operate on a `WORD` (or any text object, really) without clobbering a register?

If you want the current `WORD` in specific, then this works:

```
let input = expand('<cWORD>')
```

It's not a general solution, but it seems to fit what you're after in this particular instance.

Comment: Matt have this answer as a comment already, but this is the best answer. I won’t change who I gave the green check to, but this answer should stay here as it definitely adds value

Comment: Agreed. I did notice the comment but I thought this definitely deserved to be *an* answer. Matt does a great job at addressing the general case of any text object or visual region.